# Проксирование Nginx + node.js + socket.io. /socket.io/ отдает 404 на 80 порту

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, socket.io

У меня есть node.js с socket.io, запущен на порту 3000. Чтобы избавиться от необходимости вводить порт в конце, я проксировала запросы с этого порта на 80, вот соответствующая конфигурация nginx:

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  server_name http://мой_ip/;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  location / {  
               proxy_pass http://мой_ip:3000/;  
               proxy_http_version 1.1;  
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
               proxy_set_header Host $host;  
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }  


location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;   
    }


location  /assets/ {
    alias /var/www/html/assets/;
}

location  /node_modules/ {
    alias /var/www/html/node_modules/;
}



location ^~ /pma/ {
            alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
            index index.php index.html;
            location ~ /pma(/.*\.php) {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME localhost;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                }
        }
}
```

Если ввести :3000, все запускается нормально. Если не вводить, внешний вид - тот же, однако в консоли браузера вот это вот:

```
GET http://мой_ip/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OuAIRXk [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 55ms]
```

С течением времени таких сообщений появляется все больше. Приложение, естественно, не работает.
Для чистоты эксперимента заменила свое приложение на тестовое:

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/game.html');
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('A user connected '+socket.id);

   //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected '+socket.id);
   });

   socket.on('clientEvent', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
   
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

game.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>
   <script src = "http://мой_ip/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
   
   <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.emit('clientEvent', 'Sent an event from the client!');
   </script>
   <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

Все то же самое в консоли в браузере. Работает исключительно на своем порту 3000.
Как сделать, чтобы на 80 порту тоже все работало нормально?

Comment: думаю, в `location /` не нужен try_files и в proxy_pass должен быть `localhost` и proxy_cache_bypass не особо нужен

Comment: @nörbörnën
это сработало, только вместо localhost 127.0.0.1 указала (с локалхостом не работало). Спасибо большое, только я не могу отметить комментарий как правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  ...

  location / {  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    или
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  }

  ...
}
```

[В документации](https://socket.io/docs/v3/reverse-proxy/) предложено больше вариантов конфигураций.

Comment: это сработало, только вместо localhost 127.0.0.1 указала (с локалхостом не работало).

Comment: да, я отметил в ответе этот момент